# Does the system automatically deduct your down or upvotes to another's question, from your own reputation pots?

Tags: discussion

Does the system automatically deduct your own down or upvotes to another's question, from your own total of reputation points>

Answer (score 6):

The [help center page on reputation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) has detailed descriptions of all the cases you will earn or loose reputation points through normal use. This includes an exhaustive list of reputation changes that result when you make and receive votes.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it automatically does this.